# Float Two Divs Side By Side

Tags: html, css

I'm really sorry to post this. I've read dozens of posts on this same issue, but I just can't solve this. How do I place the blue and green boxes side-by-side? I've got plenty of space in my wrapping div, and I think that I am dealing with float correctly, but still incorrect results. What gives?

```
<div class="titleframe" >
    <div class="image" >            
        <img id="thief" src="thief.png">
    </div>

    <div class="titletext">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        <p>Line1<br>Line2<br>Line3</p>
    </div>
</div>

.titleframe {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:750px;
    clear:left;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.image {
    width:100px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.titletext{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top:0px;
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `display: inline-block;` in `.titleframe` instead of `float:left;` in `.titletext`.

Comment: Please fix your title. Don't add *garbage* to it just to circumvent the uniqueness filter.

Comment: You are not floating `.image` left.

Comment: @meagar - that wasn't for the uniqueness filter. It was for my frustration filter. My apologies. :P

Comment: Just so you know, `float` was not intended for layout alignment. It was intended for wrapping text around an image, similar to a print magazine article layout.

Comment: Sorry guess I could have made it an answer instead of a comment, Dryden Long has the correct code in his answer below.

Comment: I guess that the lesson here is that if you get stuck (and frustrated) on something simple, you have to give back a few reputation points to get the correct answer. Wow.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not too sure about that statement. Do you have anything to suggest this? W3C states that it's simply a box that is shifted to the left, right, or not at all. Isn't that what layouts are comprised of- a series of boxes placed around in some sort of design? If there's a reference out there that says it's not intended for layouts I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: @MattK Sure: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/ and http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float and this talk mentions it as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwdVU_ZJD0w The intended purpose is pretty clear, though the W3C (wisely) stops just short of calling it that; to do so would mean invalidating half the sites on the web that use the float property for layout blocking.

Comment: @MattK Another big one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/17/floats-dont-suck-if-you-use-them-right/ Because I hit the character limit.

Comment: @TylerH There doesn't seem to be any mention in those articles of a link or quote to a specification which says they should not be used for layouts. They seem opinionated and not factual. In one of the articles it says just the opposite of what you suggest- "Aside from the simple example of wrapping text around images, floats can be used to create entire web layouts.". Floats were meant for content to flow around other content, which is exactly what a layout is.

Comment: @MattK If you simply read the words and not the meaning, then sure, you won't draw the same conclusion, but that's like understanding JavaScript syntax and still not knowing really what a script does because it hasn't been commented at all. Also if you read that last link, it's pretty explicitly stated. These are all links from CSS2 era, a decade ago, so it's hard to argue that they're just opinionated; the most likely reason for scarce resources of a more definitive nature is link rot (how many links that you have ever come across from 2004 are still alive today?).

Comment: @MattK The stickler here seems to be that you are using the word *layout* to mean something different. What I mean when I say "floats are not for layout design" is that, yes, they can be used *in* layout designs. However, they should not be used *for* layout designs. Again, the last link I provided explains how the only reason floats are used for layout design is thanks to the `clear` property. `Float` should be used to float text around an image/element, not to position entire semantic sections and containers with respect to each other.

Comment: @TylerH It seems like the community disagrees. I asked the same question and received numerous comments that the subject was far too subjective, and that `float` can and will be used in this manner until there are better tools for the job.

Comment: @MattK Asked where? Just because a property is used commonly doesn't mean that is its intended or best use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:left;` to your `.image` class. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36KP5/

```
.image {
    width:100px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/25Z35/)

You can either float the first one left, and add margin-left to the second one:

```
.titleframe {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:750px;
    clear:left;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.image {
    width:100px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}

.titletext{
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 101px;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top:0px;
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Or you can float them both left.